# Как в C/C++ узнать, является ли тип знаковым или беззнаковым?

Tags: c++, c, c++11

Сталкиваясь с типами данных, подобными `time_t`, `size_t` и другими, очевидно "численными" (считая, что указатель это тоже число) типами, иногда становится просто интересно, а это *signed* или *unsigned* тип?

Как, не роясь во всех include-файлах, где находятся их определения, часто спрятанные в дебрях условных макроподстановок, выяснить это?

По крайней мере для x86_64 GNU/Linux  и компилятора gcc/g++ можно использовать простой прием, заключающийся в вычитании единицы из нуля и проверки, меньше ли нуля результат вычитания. Если меньше, то мы имеем *signed* тип, а иначе он *unsigned*.

Такой прием можно оформить парой макросов:

```
#define SIGNED_TYPE(typename) ({volatile typename v = 0; volatile typename v1 = v - 1; v > v1;})
```

определяет знаковость типа  по имени типа, а макрос

```
#define SIGNED_VAR(var) ({volatile typeof(var) v = 0, v1 = v - 1; v > v1;})
```

по переменной данного типа.

И если с первым макро все хорошо, то второй работает только при компиляции с флагом `-std=...` , определяющим GNU расширения C/C++ (в т.ч. без флага `-std=...`, т.е. "по умолчанию" для gcc/g++), а вот для `-std=c89`, `-std=c11` и т.д. не компилируется, поскольку `typeof()` это GNU расширение.

Такая модификация макроса для определения "знаковости" переменной

```
#ifndef __STRICT_ANSI__
// GNU extensions
#define SIGNED_VAR(var) ({volatile typeof(var) v = 0, v1 = v - 1; v > v1;})
#else 
#define SIGNED_VAR(var) ({var = 0; var > var - 1;})
#endif
```

конечно ужасна, во-первых, макрос меняет значение тестируемой переменной, а во-вторых (и это главное), неправильно определяет "знаковость" указателя (правильно -- *unsigned*) при компиляции в `__STRICT_ANSI__` с оптимизацией выше `-O1`.

Маленькая программа для иллюстрации.

```
// compile gcc/g++
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  time_t t = 0, t1 = t - 1;
  size_t s = 0, s1 = s - 1;
  char *p = 0, *p1 = p - 1;
  int i = 0, i1 = i - 1,
    *pp = 0, *pp1 = pp - 1;
  double d = 0, d1 = d - 1;

  printf("time_t: %ssigned\n", t1 < t ? "" : "un");
  printf("size_t: %ssigned\n", s1 < s ? "" : "un");
  printf("int:    %ssigned\n", i1 < i ? "" : "un");
  printf("double: %ssigned\n", d1 < d ? "" : "un");
  printf("char *: %ssigned\n", p1 < p ? "" : "un");
  printf("  demo for pointers\n  %p > %p %s\n", 
         pp, pp1, pp > pp1 ? "true" : "false");
  puts("\n  check macro");

#define SIGNED_TYPE(typename) ({volatile typename v = 0; volatile typename v1 = v - 1; v > v1;})

  printf("SIGNED_TYPE(time_t): %ssigned\n", SIGNED_TYPE(time_t) ? "" : "un");
  printf("SIGNED_TYPE(size_t): %ssigned\n", SIGNED_TYPE(size_t) ? "" : "un");
  printf("SIGNED_TYPE(char *): %ssigned\n", SIGNED_TYPE(char *) ? "" : "un");
  printf("SIGNED_TYPE(int):    %ssigned\n", SIGNED_TYPE(int) ? "" : "un");
  printf("SIGNED_TYPE(double): %ssigned\n", SIGNED_TYPE(double) ? "" : "un");
  printf("SIGNED_TYPE(long long):     %ssigned\n", 
         SIGNED_TYPE(long long) ? "" : "un");
  printf("SIGNED_TYPE(unsigned char): %ssigned\n", 
         SIGNED_TYPE(unsigned char) ? "" : "un");

#ifndef __STRICT_ANSI__
// GNU extensions
#define SIGNED_VAR(var) ({volatile typeof(var) v = 0, v1 = v - 1; v > v1;})
#else 
// UGLY, because change var, WRONG for -std=c++... -std=c... with -Ox
#define SIGNED_VAR(var) ({var = 0; var > var - 1;})
#endif

  printf("SIGNED_VAR(time_t t): %ssigned\n", SIGNED_VAR(t) ? "" : "un");
  printf("SIGNED_VAR(size_t s): %ssigned\n", SIGNED_VAR(s) ? "" : "un");
  printf("SIGNED_VAR(int i):    %ssigned\n", SIGNED_VAR(i) ? "" : "un");
  printf("SIGNED_VAR(double d): %ssigned\n", SIGNED_VAR(d) ? "" : "un");
  printf("SIGNED_VAR(char *p):  %ssigned\n", SIGNED_VAR(p) ? "" : "un");

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Какими еще способами можно ответить на данный вопрос и работает ли описанный метод в системах, отличных от x86_64 GNU/Linux gcc/g++ ?

P.S.
не стоит рассматривать эту задачку, как к имеющую смысл при практическом  программировании, важную для использования API с такими типами, нет, к ней можно относиться только с т.з.  удовлетворения естественного любопытства.

Comment: Поисковые запросы выводят на [википедию RTTI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Динамическая_идентификация_типа_данных) и использование заголовочного файла `typeinfo`. Если я правильно понял о чем речь, так можно проверить тип: `cout << typeid(a).name()`. Выводит он правда не очень читабельное сокращение, но это можно исправить используя [boost/core/demangle](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/core/doc/html/core/demangle.html). Ну и еще тема на [EN-SO: Print a variables type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c) похожая.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37943/discussion-on-question-by-avp---c-c-------).

Comment: @AlexKrass ок, вернул старый комментарий, вроде бы там немного другой текст.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

В С++ для этого есть `std::is_signed<T>`, `std::is_unsigned<T>`.

В Си можно написать макрос, который будет преобразовывать литерал `0` и выражение `-1` к нужному типу:

```
#define IS_SIGNED_TYPE(type) ((type)0 > (type)-1)
```

Для переменных можно было бы использовать `var^var` чтобы получить 0 нужного типа. Но это работает только для целых чисел. Так же нам надо получить `(type)-1` что невозможно если использовать только арифметические операции, например тип `var^var - 1` - это `int`.
По этому надо использовать такое расширение компилятора, например `__typeof__`.

```
#define IS_SIGNED_VAR(var) (IS_SIGNED_TYPE(__typeof__(var)))
```

Comment: Первый макрос можно упростить до `((type)0 > (type)-1)`. К тому же это исключит предупреждения компилятора при проверке беззнаковых типов (при компиляции в `c++` gcc).

Comment: Может где-то и работает, а у меня (gcc/g++ 4.8.4 c разными -std= и даже без оптимизации) IS_SIGNED_VAR всегда signed, а IS_SIGNED_TYPE для unsigned char и unsigned short тоже signed/ @Abyx, Вы на чем проверяли?

Comment: @avp, Вы бы ссылку привели на онлайн компилятор. Я вот вижу, что [всё ок](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HcwGGRnFGbIubsKc).

Comment: @alexolut, я не онлайн, я дома `avp@avp-ubu1:hash_misc$ uname -a; gcc --vers
Linux avp-ubu1 3.13.0-83-generic #127-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 11 00:25:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
gcc.real (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4`

Comment: @alexolut, вот в чем дело-то -- сейчас (и у Вас в online-compile) `#define IS_SIGNED_TYPE(type) ((type)(0) > (type)-1)`, а раньше (до безмолвного исправления ответа) было `#define IS_SIGNED_TYPE(type) ((type)(0) > (type)0 -1)` (я с таким и проверял) / Теперь IS_SIGNED_TYPE **работает правильно** (ОК, Abyx, он мне нравится более моего)

Comment: Кстати, IS_SIGNED_TYPE теперь правильно работает и с указателями (и в C++ тоже).

Comment: Осталось починить `IS_SIGNED_VAR`. Для начала, нужно больше скобок: `(((var)^(var)) > (((var)^(var)) - 1))`. Т.к. в исходном варианте для `42u` возвращает вообще `3`. Но это всё равно не решает задачу при передаче именованной переменной типа `unsigned char` например.

Comment: @Abyx, OK. Мне нравится. Удалим комментарии?

Answer (score 10):

По-моему, в С++ для этого есть такая вещь, как type traits, и конкретно `is_signed` и `is_unsigned`...

```
cout << "size_t is" << (is_signed<size_t>::value ? " " : " un") << "signed\n";
cout << "time_t is" << (is_signed<time_t>::value ? " " : " un") << "signed\n";
cout << "int    is" << (is_signed<int>::value ? " " : " un") << "signed\n";
cout << "long   is" << (is_signed<long>::value ? " " : " un") << "signed\n";
```

Кстати, напомню, что `is_signed != !is_unsigned` - если для какого-то типа они оба дают `false`, то, вообще говоря, говорить о знаковости или беззнаковости не приходится. Знаков или беззнаков тип `vector`? :)

И еще - о С++ же и методе, описанном в вопросе. `typeof()` лучше бы заменить на `decltype()`, нет? Выражение вида `({...})` и в самом деле непереносимо. Лучше воспользоваться лямбдой:

```
auto signed_var = [](auto x) { volatile decltype(x) z = 0, z1 = z - 1; return z > z1; };

int x;
unsigned int z;
cout << signed_var(x) << endl;
cout << signed_var(z) << endl;
```

**Update**
В С+11 использование type traits требует включения

```
#include <type_traits>
```

Что касается того, к какому стандарту относится эта возможность, то как часть `numeric_limits` она описана как минимум в С++98 (ISO/IEC 14882:1998). Просто в старых версиях (впрочем, из-за обратной совместимости можно и в новых) надо включать

```
#include<limits>
```

и использовать как

```
cout << numeric_limits<int>::is_signed << endl;
cout << numeric_limits<unsigned int>::is_signed << endl;
```

Comment: Это же только для C++, **начиная с 11** (а, скажем, в ubuntu 14.04 LTE(!) g++ по умолчанию еще не 11). И добавьте, что нужно `#include <type_traits>` подключить.

Comment: @avp Гм, точно с C++11? Дело в том, что это есть даже в таком компиляторе, как старый добрый Open Watcom 1.9 выпуска 2002 года...

Comment: По крайней мере в gcc приходится писать `g++ -std=c++11` или `-std=gnu++11`

Comment: @avp Как минимум нашел у себя в загашнике ISO/IEC 14882:1998(E) - там это есть, просто как часть `numeric_limits`. Попробуйте у себя включить `<limits>` и использовать `numeric_limits<TYPE>::is_signed`

Comment: Да, `numeric_limits<T>::is_signed` у меня без -std= тоже работает (и в т.ч. для указателей).

Answer (score 2):

Решение (несколько уродское) уровня `c11` для определения знаковости значений на основании `_Generic`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IS_SIGNED_TYPE(type) ((type)0 > (type)-1)

#define IS_SIGNED_VAR(x) _Generic((x), \
        unsigned char:      IS_SIGNED_TYPE(unsigned char), \
        char:               IS_SIGNED_TYPE(char), \
        signed char:        IS_SIGNED_TYPE(signed char), \
        short:              IS_SIGNED_TYPE(short), \
        unsigned short:     IS_SIGNED_TYPE(unsigned short), \
        int:                IS_SIGNED_TYPE(int), \
        unsigned:           IS_SIGNED_TYPE(unsigned), \
        long:               IS_SIGNED_TYPE(long), \
        unsigned long:      IS_SIGNED_TYPE(unsigned long), \
        long long:          IS_SIGNED_TYPE(long long), \
        unsigned long long: IS_SIGNED_TYPE(unsigned long long), \
        float:              IS_SIGNED_TYPE(float), \
        double:             IS_SIGNED_TYPE(double), \
        long double:        IS_SIGNED_TYPE(long double), \
        void*:              IS_SIGNED_TYPE(void*), \
        default:            0) 

int main()
{
    unsigned char s;
    printf("%d\n", IS_SIGNED_VAR(s));
    printf("%d\n", IS_SIGNED_VAR(42));
    printf("%d\n", IS_SIGNED_VAR(100u)); 
}
```

<kbd>[Результат clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QLpBA20zy3AuF2Gi)</kbd>
<kbd>[Результат gcc](http://ideone.com/yOUPTs)</kbd>

Замечу, что [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc)  [поддерживает](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status) `_Generic` только с версии 4.9.

Comment: Да, я тоже кручу разные варианты. Вроде бы  `__typeof__()` вместо `typeof()` поддерживается несколькими компиляторами (в т.ч. и gcc). Тогда простой `#define IS_SIGNED_VAR(var) (IS_SIGNED_TYPE(__typeof__(var)))` выглядит хорошим решением. Можете проверить на чем-нибудь кроме gcc/g++?

Comment: @avp под `clang` собирается, но вот под `msvc` - [не получилось](http://rextester.com/FRNRV59382)

Comment: Спасибо, я тоже уже проверил clang. А m$? -- это же особый мир (у них даже / перевернут :-))

Comment: @Abyx, про MS речь шла уже в контексте `__typeof__`. Но это вообще не регламентированная стандартами вещь. `C11` возможно когда-нибудь и запилят, к выходу VS2030 наверное :) `C99` вон в vs2015 уже поддерживается в некоторой степени.

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю просто для коллекции. В С++ можно еще и так проверить:

```
template <class T> inline bool _is_signed (T value) { return value = (T)-1, value < 0; }
```

Подобный код и до 11-го стандарта должен отработать.

Comment: Это уже есть в принятом ответе, хоть и в виде макроса.

Comment: Ну, это все таки не макрос и если подходить формально то следовало бы написать так `(T)-1 < (T)0` в этом случае было бы полное соответствие тому, что указано в ответе. А в целом, да, принцип тот же.

Answer (score 0):

> И если с первым макро все хорошо, то второй работает только при компиляции с флагом -std=... , определяющим GNU расширения C/C++ (в т.ч. без флага -std=..., т.е. "по умолчанию" для gcc/g++), а вот для -std=c89, -std=c11 и т.д. не компилируется, поскольку typeof() это GNU расширение.

Второй, думаю, можно просто привязать к свойству "расширения знака" при сдвиге вправо, что-то вроде такого:

```
#define SIGNED_VAR(var)    ((var < 0) || ((~var >> 1) < 0))
```

Вариант не работает с `char` и `short`, т.к. `~var` в таком случае преобразуется к типу `signed int`.

для их поддержки придется задействовать typeof:

```
#define SIGNED_VAR(var)    ((var < 0) || ((((__typeof__(var))~var) >> 1) < 0))
```

[Пример на ideone](https://ideone.com/4nCIHA)

Comment: Это не работает как хотелось бы. Проверьте сами: `unsigned char c; SIGNED_VAR(c)`.

Comment: Вот так решили `#define IS_SIGNED_VAR(var) (IS_SIGNED_TYPE(__typeof__(var)))`

Comment: @alexolut, если Вы о неинициализированной переменной, то в Си это не имеет значения. А вот с самим типом char (да и с short, по всей видимости) тут проблема в том, что оператор ~ (bitwise not) преобразует операнд к int'у, со всеми вытекающими. Видимо, без typeof все же не обойтись. С int'ами только работает и long long )

Comment: @mega я имел в виду именно проблему преобразования типов. Поэтому и появились варианты с _Generic и всякими typeof. А насчет отсутствия инициализации не будьте так уверены. Из-за наличия trap representation в знаковых типах, код вообще может приводить к UB.

Comment: "я имел в виду именно проблему преобразования типов" -- быть может, Вы это имели ввиду, но ничего для этого не написали ). trap representation, насколько я понимаю - рудимент который ни кто сейчас не поддерживает. Логически, формула верная, попробуйте на int'ах и long long'ах.

Comment: @mega, я не написал о преобразовании в `int`, т.к. об этом уже было сказано в ответе @Abyx. trap representation в Стандарте присутствует, а значит надо иметь это в виду. В п.6.2.6.1/5 c11 сказано, что чтение такого значения с присваиванием не символьному типу приводит к UB. Т.о. преобразование `indeterminate value` в `int` есть UB.

Comment: "trap representation в Стандарте присутствует, а значит надо иметь это в виду" -- ну да, имейте ввиду, если Вам больше нечем заняться. Про int я уже написал, каких типов он касается, не понял, при чем тут @Abyx.

Answer (score -5):

Применительно к С++ в объектно-ориентированном программировании мы оперируем не типами, а классами. По умолчанию объект какого-либо класса - это ссылка на объект.

Например

```
class Time {
private:
   time_t m_time;
public:
   operator int () const;
   operator unsigned int () const;
};
```

Как следует из приведённого примера, не имеет смысла говорить о том, знакового типа или беззнакового типа является объект класса `Time`, хотя с точки зрения Си этот объект - просто ячейка в памяти, хранящая значение типа `time_t`.