# Не понимаю почему for выполняется

Tags: c, типы

Не думал что задам такой вопрос но при переделывании кода с `Pascal` в `C` получилась странность.
`Pascal`:

```pascal
for j := 1 to Length(tmp)-1 do begin
```

и `C`

```c
for(j = 1; j <= strlen(tmp)-1; j ++) {
```

Это оказывается разные вещи при `Length(tmp)=0`...

Comment: не помещайте ответ в ваш вопрос. Если хотите, то опубликуйте ваше решение как ответ. Это [явно поощряется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 4):

Оказывается в отладчике и в реальности вещи ведут себя по-разному. Ломал голову понял , в реальности: `(strlen(tmp) - 1)` не `-1` )) Т.к `strlen` возвращает `size_t` (implementation этого типа я не нашёл) а это `unsigned` то C почему-то работает с `(strlen(tmp) - 1)` как с `unsigned` и соотв-но результатом будет `макс_ПОЛОЖИТЕЛЬНОЕ_значение_size_t - 1` ... А отладчик считал что `(strlen(tmp) - 1)` типа `signed` и отображал -1 как результат и более того в отладчике `j <= (strlen(tmp) - 1) == 0` а в реальности `j <= (strlen(tmp) - 1) == 1` по указанной причине... Вот так вот "весело" программировать на  C)
Исправляется это кстати так: `for(j = 1; j <= (signed)(strlen(tmp) - 1); j ++)`

Comment: Вот [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509298) мы рассматривали `#define` для определения "знаковости" неизвестного типа (и переменной этого типа).

Comment: Спасибо @avp! Вы меня еще с детства (моего) (на тогда еще hashcode) учите)))

Comment: Хм.. Почему то @avp не работает. Хэшкод уже не тот(((

Comment: Серьезно? Вот эти 2 defiene `#define IS_SIGNED_TYPE(type) ((type)(0) > (type)-1)` и `#define IS_SIGNED_VAR(var) (IS_SIGNED_TYPE(__typeof__(var)))` не работают? А как проверяли? У меня (и gcc ... и g++ и g++ -std=c++11) `printf("size_t: %ssigned ssize_t %ssigned\n",
  IS_SIGNED_TYPE(size_t) ? "" : "un",
  IS_SIGNED_TYPE(ssize_t) ? "" : "un");` прекрасно работает

Answer (score 3):

Опередили))

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    if (j < i - 1)
        printf("OK\n");
    else
        printf("NO\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Печатает ОК. Аккуратнее с signed и unsigned типами, у меня компилятор выдает ворнинг на сравнение

Comment: А у вас какой компилятор? У меня gnu gcc в codeblocks не предупреждает...

Comment: Угу. 4.8.4 не ругается даже с `-Wall -pedantic`.

Comment: @Rules g++ 4.4.7 `g++ -W main.c "main.c:7: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions"`. MSVC 2013 в QtCreator тоже ругается в DEBUG-mode

Comment: @Rules: при настройках рекомендуемых [здесь вообще ошибка компиляции выдаётся](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1667114): `andy.37.c:7:11: error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Werror=sign-compare]` (что оправдано, сравнение чисел со знаком с числами без знака ведёт к багам--в вашем случае вероятно нужно явно в `int` преобразовать).

Comment: 1) `gcc` и `g++` всё-таки немного разные компиляторы :) 2) так явно же сказано "считать предупреждения ошибками"

Comment: @PinkTux: `gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20111023 (prerelease) [svn/rev.180339 - mingw-w64/oz]` Один и тот же вывод у `gcc --version` и `g++ --version`. Скорее странно, что у Вас не ругается

Comment: @andy.37 не, с полным набором ключей по ссылке (точнее, с `-Werror=sign-compare`) конечно ругань. Но без него - только g++реагирует, gcc молчит. Оба такие: `(Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4`

Comment: О так реально ошибка а даже с -Wall (но без -Werror=sign-compare) нет